# How can I print a set of images from different folders in Lightroom?

Tags: printing, lightroom-4

Is it possible to create a set of prints from different folders? I have tried but when I enter another folder the images from the previous folder disappear from the layout.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?
Do you have the same pictures in 2 separate folders? And if so, what would be the purpose of that?
Did you try experimenting with "Collections"?

Answer (score 1):

From memory the best thing to do would be to create a collection first. If you are likely to do this sort of thing often, you could create a collection set, naming it something like 'Print sets', and have several collections within it. When you go to the Print screen, you can choose the collection to print from.

If you want to make adjustments to the images specific to printing (for example, my printer darkens everything, so I would increase the exposure to allow for that, but that means it doesn't  display correctly onscreen), then when you add the images to the collections, you can choose to create virtual copies, so that a new copy of the image is what gets adjusted instead

Comment: I see what you're saying and to be honest this is the only method I could think of but it's a bit annoying to have to do it this way. I just had a thought that perhaps rather than clicking on the sub folder, if I click the parent folder which shows all images within it, this could work?

Comment: @connersz Presumably you can, but then you'd have to search through lots of images. I'm not sure if you can apply filters in this view? I'd have to check on that when I next get into Lightroom

Comment: There's a "Quick collection" tool (the little dot at the top of images) that can make for a simple way to do this without creating a specific collection for each printout.

Answer (score 0):

A few solutions from the top of my head, all of which involve you selecting the right images.

- Make a collection, above post.
- Make a tag, color it or mark it somehow, and select only those by sorting
- If you aren't planning to edit post print, output each folder and what you want.